# JUnit test cases for encoding a JSON object and array

Tags: json, junit

I am new to using JUnit and JSON and I am looking for any example test cases for encoding and decoding a JSON object and a JSON array. How would something like this be done?

Comment: Wow, you are leaving out some things ... what is the code you want to test? I assume you have some POJO with Annotations of some framework? Which framework? Did you manage to get a system.out of the produced json?

Comment: I'm looking for an example...like encoding a JSONObject with single key/value pairs as well as a JSONArray test for the encoding of multiple JSONObjects in the array. I am writing the tests before coding (TDD).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a library already established like FlexJSON. Then add a method to your objects that uses the library to convert the object into a JSON string. It also provides converting from JSON to the object which makes unit testing a cinch!

http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/

Read the documentation it's super easy to work with...

Comment: I don't believe we can use that on this, but I see how it would make it easier.